# Declare numerical value in cell is hour

Tags: excel

I want to declare a specific value in a cell is an hour.  For example I have 24 in a cell and I want that to be considered 24hours.

This way I can use a formula to calculate a new date and time.

I have a list of numbers I need to directly use for hours.

```
24 - Need to represent as 24 hours
13 - Need to represent as 13 hours
14 - Need to represent as 14 hours
6 - Need to represent as 6 hours
8 - Need to represent as 8 hours
```

Comment: In a blank column use this `=Time(A1,,)` then copy and paste the values back.

Comment: Not working :( In my column that shows 24 it gives me 00:00:00 (when the column is formatted hh:mm:ss

Comment: Why don't you just divide the whole cell by 24 (either by Paste Special or by creating an additional column with `=RC[-1]/24`) and use that one? It will format correctly when you use number format `[h]` and you can simply add them together or to a date field.

Comment: And here we are over thinking it, good catch @CompuChip

Comment: Yeah, technically it's not an answer to the question but it _may_ be an answer to the _actual_ problem. I think I'll take my chances and just post it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this vba.  Select the group and run:

```
Sub hr()
Selection.NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm:ss"
Selection.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(INT(" & Selection.Address(0, 0) & "/24)+TIME(" & Selection.Address(0, 0) & ", 0, 0),)")

End Sub
```

For a formula version:

In a empty column:

```
=INT(A1/24)+Time(A1,,)
```

And Copy down.  Then copy and paste the values onto the column you want and format that column `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Nice use of *Evaluate()*

Comment: That was slick Scott Craner!  I see how you did that, I couldn't have figured this out on my own.  Great job.

Comment: Using what @CompuChip said you can reduce the evaluate formula to `Selection.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(" & Selection.Address(0, 0) & "/24,)")` and get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub HourByHour()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(r) Then
            r.Value = TimeSerial(r.Value, 0, 0)
            r.NumberFormat = "h"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To get 24 to display as 24, use this macro instead:

```
Sub HourByHour()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(r) Then
            r.Value = TimeSerial(r.Value, 0, 0)
            r.NumberFormat = "[h]"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok - when I run this a column that has 24 in it will return 00:00:00 when formatted in hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Yogwhatup  What NumberFormat do you want to use for 24 hours ??

Comment: I want every number in that column to literally equal hours. So a 6 in that column would equal 6 hours. I appreciate everyone's help with this :)

Comment: @Yogwhatup  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to treat it as a time value, why don't you make it a time value?
You can divide the whole cell by 24 using Paste Special, if it's a one-time operation, or you can create an additional column with `=RC[-1]/24`.

Advantage of storing the value in days, is that it will format correctly when you use the number format `[h]`, in addition you can simply add values together or add them to a date field.

[image]